# apps installed with ubuntu software won't start

Tags: software-installation, software-center

So I have created an ubuntu live persistent USB drive.

Everything seems to work ok. I installed CLion, atom and spotify using Ubuntu Software but none of the 3 runs!

I click on the icon and just nothing happens.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Son VAIO pc from 2013 and I already did `apt-get update`.

---

**Workaround but yet not a definite fix:**

I removed clion and install it following the instructions on the main page [Install and set up CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/install-and-set-up-product.html) and it works perfectly!

I also removed atom and installed by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

And now is working. It seams to me a problem with ubuntu software center... maybe a problem with gnome? I have no idea why this happens.

---

**Debugging atom:** (when it was not working)

When debugging atom I tried several commands like `atom -f` or `atom --safe` or `atom -v` and got:

```
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be.
Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
```

So I runned them as sudo and got:

```
cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory
```

Because of the comments I output this other information:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ sudo apt policy atom
N: Unable to locate package atom
ubuntu@ubuntu:$ sudo snap info atom
name:      atom
summary:   A hackable text editor for the 21st Century.
publisher: snapcrafters
contact:   https://github.com/snapcrafters/atom/issues
license:   unknown
description: |
  Atom is a free and open source text editor that is modern,
  approachable, and hackable to the core.

  This snap is maintained by the Snapcrafters community, and is not
  necessarily endorsed or officially maintained by the upstream developers.
commands:
  - atom.apm
  - atom
snap-id:      Lf1MF6tizzusVuA6l13ETyH5VDXxwA0D
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: today at 19:37 UTC
channels:                       
  stable:    1.31.2 (202) 187MB classic
  candidate: ↑                  
  beta:      1.31.2 (202) 187MB classic
  edge:      1.31.2 (202) 187MB classic
installed:   1.31.2 (202) 187MB classic
```

---

**Hardware/drivers information**

I think it might be some drivers problem so I runned `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and now I have nvidia's propietary drivers up and running.
This is how it is currently set up after my drivers autoinstall command:
[image]

---

Ok, so now I'm puzzled. I had concluded anything installed on ubuntu software didn't worked but today (16-10-2018) I installed pinta with ubuntu software and it worked. 
I tried reinstalling spotify to see if it was an update but problem persist.

Comment: Can you add the following information, so we can better help. Does your laptop have an nvidia GPU? Did you restart after all the installations (shouldn't be needed if everything was ok). If you type `apt policy atom` and `snap info atom` from the terminal what do you get?

Comment: I did reboot.
I have a NVIDIA GeForce GT 735M.

Comment: Also having issues specifically with spotify, running it from the terminal returns the same error